# Optimization in Julia with Optim.jl - How do I get rid of this error?

Tags: function, optimization, julia, minimize, minimization

newbie here

I'm trying to minimize a function in Julia with optim.jl. The function works, but when I try to optimize it it gives me this error message:

```
MethodError: no method matching -(::Float64, ::Array{Float64,1})
For element-wise subtraction, use broadcasting with dot syntax: scalar .- array
Closest candidates are:
  -(::Float64, !Matched::Float64) at float.jl:403
  -(::Float64) at float.jl:393
  -(::Real, !Matched::Complex{Bool}) at complex.jl:302
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] _broadcast_getindex_evalf at ./broadcast.jl:648 [inlined]
 [2] _broadcast_getindex at ./broadcast.jl:621 [inlined]
 [3] getindex at ./broadcast.jl:575 [inlined]
 [4] copy at ./broadcast.jl:876 [inlined]
 [5] materialize at ./broadcast.jl:837 [inlined]
 [6] broadcast_preserving_zero_d at ./broadcast.jl:826 [inlined]
 [7] -(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Array{Float64,1},1}) at ./arraymath.jl:39
 [8] objective(::Array{Float64,1}) at ./In[147]:4
 [9] value!!(::NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /ext/julia/depot/packages/NLSolversBase/NsXIC/src/interface.jl:9
 [10] initial_state(::NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}, ::NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /ext/julia/depot/packages/Optim/TNmSw/src/multivariate/solvers/zeroth_order/nelder_mead.jl:158
 [11] optimize(::NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}) at /ext/julia/depot/packages/Optim/TNmSw/src/multivariate/optimize/optimize.jl:33
 [12] optimize(::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}; inplace::Bool, autodiff::Symbol, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /ext/julia/depot/packages/Optim/TNmSw/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:64
 [13] optimize(::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /ext/julia/depot/packages/Optim/TNmSw/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:58
 [14] top-level scope at In[148]:3
 [15] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1091
```

This is my code:

```
function objective(b)
    x = x1[:,2]
    b = fill(b,T)
    u = y - x.*b
    obj = sum(u.^2)
    return obj
end

using Optim

Sol = optimize(objective,[0.0;0.0])
b_optim = Optim.minimizer(Sol)
```

, where x and y are Array{Float64,1}

I don't understand this error message. If I understand it correctly, it tells me that I'm trying to subtract an array from a number, which I'm not doing?! Broadcasting also doesn't work.

Comment: You don't define either `x1` nor `y` within the function, so the functon is taking the values of these two variables from the general scope. I would guess that contrarily to what you say, `y` is a `Float64` and not an Array.

Comment: By the way also `T` is undefined in your function. You should either pass the variables as arguments or define them within the funciton.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have much more code and defined everything above, but I didn't want to show the whole thing. x1, y and T don't change so I haven't included them in the formula. So are you saying they all have to be in the function in order for it to work? (i.e. function objective(x1,y,b,T)?

Comment: No, it works also if they are in the general scope, but it is not good practice to do so, because you cannot be sure of what they really are and the function cannot be optimized by the JIT compiler. I would pass them as arguments so that you can make no mistakes and to debug you can try to write a `println(y)` in your function, so that you see what it really is.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on that. I printed y and it is a column vector (Array{Float64,1}). The thong is that the function doesn't return an error message when i run it, but the function used in the optimization does, so I think the mistake has to be in the optimization part somewhere

Comment: Maybe try giving a minimum reproducible example, so that it is easier to understand where the problem lies. I.e. also give the values of `y,x1,T`

Comment: y: -5.385
     1.618
    -7.089
   -24.638
   -10.731
   -12.710
     4.299 .......

Comment: x1: '''' 197001.000    -8.100     2.900     3.040     0.600
197002.000     5.130    -2.400     4.040     0.620
197003.000    -1.060    -2.320     4.250     0.570
197004.000   -11.000    -6.110     6.390     0.500
197005.000    -6.920    -4.520     3.600     0.530
197006.000    -5.790    -2.160     0.870     0.580 ''''

Comment: Edit your question and put them there, it is easier. There is no good multiline code formatting in comments.

Comment: Ok so you want to do `b.=T` I guess? What do you want to do with fill?

Comment: I did it above, thanks. I'm filling a vector with b with length T so that I can multiply all the values of x with b (therse probably an easier way, I know)

Comment: ok, usually it is good practice to shrink down your example down to the minimum. I.e. try to put the arrays of reasonable length (for example `y = rand(4)`). The things that matter are that it is of the right shape (1D or 2D, same length as other arrays). Like this it is still hard to use it to reproduce the error.

Comment: And to subtract all the values of `x` with `b` you don't need to do the fill step, it is just allocating unnecessarily a new array. If it is of the right shape it should work just with broadcasting.

Comment: You're right. I removed the fill step and now there's a new error message: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 595 and 2")

Comment: so your `x` is a 1D array of length 595, and b is a 1D array of length 2. How do you want to multiply them together? With `fill(b,595)` you get an `595-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`. Multiplied with x you get still a `595-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`.  You cannot subtract that from a `595-element Array{Float64,1}:`. They have to be of the same shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add arguments to your function, so that you can be sure you're passing the right variables. Then you should not use `fill(b,T)` as it allocates a new array uselessly. Furthermore, if you have an univariate problem you should give to the solver only one variable and as written in the documentation ([Optim.jl/stable/#user/minimization/](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#user/minimization/)) you should use another solver, like `LBFGS()`.

Summing up this would look like:

```
using Optim
function objective(b, x1, y)
    x = x1[:,2]
    u = y - x.*b
    obj = sum(u.^2)
    return obj
end

x1 = rand(10,10)
y = rand(10)
Sol = optimize(b -> objective(b,x1,y),[0.0], LBFGS())
b_optim = Optim.minimizer(Sol)
```

Comment: I did that, thanks. However, the error message stays the same :/

Comment: I guess the problem lies in the way you fill `b`. I.e. something like `hcat(fill(b,T)...)` maybe could work? still it doesn't look beautiful

Comment: Isn't the problem that y is a scalar when it shouldn't be? Because b is an array, which is correct

Comment: No, as you said `y` is an Array, but if you try `[0.,0.] - [[0.,0.],[0.,0.]]` it gives you the same error as it tries to subtract the first element of the first array from the first element of the second array. There lies the problem. the shape of the arrays is not the same and the second one is a nested array, while the first one is not.

Comment: ok, and does that come from the starting point of the optimization? ([0.0:0.0])? I tried to change that but it can't be just 0.0 somehow?

Comment: It needs to be an array, see [Optim.jl/stable/#user/minimization/](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#user/minimization/) for documentation. With an univariate problem you need to use another solver though. For example you can run it with `optimize(b -> objective(b,x1,y,T),[0.0], LBFGS())`
I hope this works now!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll change the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate your error via:

```
julia> 4 - [2,5]
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching -(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1})
```

That it means is that your `y` is not a vector as expected but a scalar.

One possible way to address the issue is to broadcast `-`:

```
julia> 4 .- [2,5]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
 -1
```

Another problem with your code already mentioned in comments are global variables. You should never do that due to type stability and performance. For sure now it is the time to read: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: Thanks, I will watch out for global variables in the future.

Comment: However, y is not a scalar in my case. When I print it it's a column vector. Broadcasting also doesn't change the result

Comment: Shouldn't your `objective` be a scalar rather than a vector?

Comment: If you're referring to the output of the objective function: that is a scalar, I just checked. But that wouldn't produce this error, right?